# Resolving Dependencies in creating JAR through SBT assembly

Tags: jvm, sbt, sbt-assembly

I want to create a big Jar file. for which am trying to use **SBT ASSEMBLY**. I installed sbt-assembly from [GitHub](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791955/assembly-merge-strategy-issues-using-sbt-assembly). When I ran `sbt assembly`, I got this error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
/home/UserName/.ivy2/cache/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit/javax.servlet/orbits/javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar:javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.class
/home/UserName/.ivy2/cache/org.mortbay.jetty/servlet-api/jars/servlet-api-2.5-20081211.jar:javax/servlet/SingleThreadModel.class
```

To solve this, I followed User's README page and this is the code he suggests.

```
mergeStrategy in assembly <<= (mergeStrategy in assembly) { (old) =>
  {
    case PathList("org", "apache", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("javax", "servlet", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("com", "esotericsoftware", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("project.clj") => MergeStrategy.last
    case PathList("overview.html") => MergeStrategy.last
    case x => old(x)
  }
}
```

Even after adding this code, I get the same error mentioned before. Please let me know what I am missing. Any help on this error will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Update 2 :**

Added the exlusion rule as per the link given,

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "0.8.0-incubating","com.codahale" % "jerkson_2.9.1" % "0.5.0","org.skife.com.typesafe.config" % "typesafe-config" % "0.3.0").map(_.exclude("javax", "servlet"))
```

**Update 3:**

I can locate the library that is causing the issue.

```
| +-org.apache.avro:avro-ipc:1.7.4
| | +-io.netty:netty:3.4.0.Final (evicted by: 3.5.4.Final)
| | +-io.netty:netty:3.5.4.Final
...
...
| | +-org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26
| | +-org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:6.1.26
| | | +-org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26
| | | +-org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211
| | | 
| | +-org.mortbay.jetty:servlet-api:2.5-20081211
| | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.2
...
... 
| +-org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-server:7.6.8.v20121106
| | +-org.eclipse.jetty.orbit:javax.servlet:2.5.0.v201103041518
```

**Update 4 : Fix**

**So adding MergeStrategy did solve the problem.** Even though I had quite a few dependencies, more than 10, adding MergeStrategy for each one of them individually **solved the issue.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are trying to treat the symptoms, but your problem actually isn't assembly: Your project has a library twice in two different versions on the class path (`javax.servlet`).

If these versions are binary compatible (which I don't know), you would be fine by excluding one of the two occurrences in your build file [like so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10958215/how-to-exclude-commons-logging-from-a-scala-sbt-slf4j-project#10959559). If they incompatible, you will need to unroll your dependency graph (a good way to do this might be the [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin) and try to find matching versions.

In any case, it might be useful to (at least transitorily) keep the libraries in the project folder. If you add `retrieveManaged in ThisBuild := true` to your sbt build file, all the libraries will be found in `<project-root>/lib_managed`. This allows you to see which jars are actually there.

---

**EDIT**: Showing the dependency graph:

Add to `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("net.virtual-void" % "sbt-dependency-graph" % "0.7.4")
```

Add to `build.sbt`:

```
net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

Then run `sbt dependency-graph`.

Comment: Thanks! Actually, I have already added `retrieveManaged` argument in sbt file.I can see the jar the that is causing this issue under `lib_managed/jars/org.mortbay.jetty/servlet-api/`. As per the link, I added [Update 2,in question] and still I face the issue. How to locate the exact library that is causing the issue ?

Comment: Have you used the dependency graph plugin? That should help you find out where the jar comes from. I have added the information.

Comment: I have got the above dependency tree.Any pointers on how do I workaround this MergeStrategy error ?

Comment: I don't see `javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar` in your print out. Anyway, if you find the artefact from which it is referenced, you can add an `exclude` statement there, hoping that you won't run into a binary class incompatibility. If you _do_ (e.g. there are `AbstractMethodError`s), the only solution is to find versions of your dependencies which have a matching version for that library. If all fails, you might have to fork one of those projects and compile it against the servlet-api version you are using...

Comment: oops, my bad. I missed that `javax.servlet-2.5.0.v201103041518.jar`! Updated the dependency graph output.

Answer (score 5):

You can also refer [This Tech Blog](http://blog.prabeeshk.com/blog/2014/04/08/creating-uber-jar-for-spark-project-using-sbt-assembly/)

Creating a single JAR for Spark project using sbt-assembly

This post is about how to create a fat jar for spark streaming project using sbt plugin. sbt-assembly is a sbt plugin to create a fat JAR of sbt project with all of its dependencies.