# Spark job server installation on hdisght

Tags: azure, apache-spark, azure-hdinsight

I have created a azure hdinsight spark cluster and I am trying to install Spark Job Server on the headnode. I have ssh'ed into the headnode and here are the steps I am following

Its HDI 3.5 with Spark 1.6.3

1. Install SBT:

echo "deb https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/debian /" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/sbt.list

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2EE0EA64E40A89B84B2DF73499E82A75642AC823

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install sbt

2. git clone https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver.git

The master is for spark 1.6.3, so I am not changing branches.

3. Moving into the spark-observer directory
4. sbt assembly 
   At this point I am getting errors like this

*

```
[warn] Merging 'reference.conf' with strategy 'concat'
[error] 1 error was encountered during merge
java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-all/jars/netty-all-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
/home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:140)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:67)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:57)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$.apply(Assembly.scala:83)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:240)
    at sbtassembly.Assembly$$anonfun$assemblyTask$1.apply(Assembly.scala:237)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Building python API received non-zero exit code 1
    at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
    at PythonTasks$.buildPythonTask(PythonTasks.scala:25)
    at $b9e935155022d705b7b0$$anonfun$jobServerPythonSettings$5.apply(build.sbt:110)
    at $b9e935155022d705b7b0$$anonfun$jobServerPythonSettings$5.apply(build.sbt:110)
    at scala.Function1$$anonfun$compose$1.apply(Function1.scala:47)
    at sbt.$tilde$greater$$anonfun$$u2219$1.apply(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
    at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:63)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:17)
    at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:237)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.Execute$$anonfun$submit$1.apply(Execute.scala:228)
    at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$anonfun$1.apply(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:159)
    at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (root/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-all/jars/netty-all-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-handler/jars/netty-handler-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-buffer/jars/netty-buffer-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-common/jars/netty-common-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-transport/jars/netty-transport-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] /home/kmk/.ivy2/cache/io.netty/netty-codec/jars/netty-codec-4.0.37.Final.jar:META-INF/io.netty.versions.properties
[error] (job-server-python/*:buildPython) Building python API received non-zero exit code 1
[error] Total time: 151 s, completed Apr 1, 2017 3:41:54 PM
```

*

What I am doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

According to your error information, per my experience, I think the issue was caused by the conflict of different version for these jars which be named by same package name. So a normal way is to try to delete these duplicate jars. Or you can refer to the offical document [`Excluding JARs and files`](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly#excluding-jars-and-files) for `sbt` to resolve dependencies via merge strategy, there is a SO thread [Resolving Dependencies in creating JAR through SBT assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19606243/resolving-dependencies-in-creating-jar-through-sbt-assembly) which may help for you as reference.

Meanwhile, according to [`manual steps`](https://github.com/spark-jobserver/spark-jobserver#manual-steps) for `spark-job-server` deployment,  the `sbt job-server/assembly` operation seems not to be necessary, which depend on your current envionment.

Hope it helps.