# Scala SBT Assembly cannot merge due to de-duplication error in StaticLoggerBinder.class

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-assembly

My problem is I can no longer use the sbt-assembly plugin because some kind of dependency merge problem creeped in, between a couple people working on this project.

The problem when I run 'sbt assembly' :

> [error] 3 errors were encountered during merge
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: deduplicate: different file contents found
>   in the following:
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
>   deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
>   deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.1.2.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
>   /Users/aris.vlasakakis/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.applyStrategies(Assembly.scala:140)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:25)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.x$1$1(Assembly.scala:23)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:23)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.stratMapping$1(Assembly.scala:23)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$lzycompute$1(Assembly.scala:67)
>           at sbtassembly.Assembly$.inputs$1(Assembly.scala:57)

... and so on

```
I am using SBT-assembly 0.13.0, and here is the build.sbt

name := "metamorphosis"

version := "0.10.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

lazy val common = RootProject(file("../"))

val main = Project(id = "bridge", base = file(".")).dependsOn(common)

//excludeDependencies += "org.apache.logging.log4j"

resolvers ++= Seq(
//  "Akka Snapshot Repository" at "http://repo.akka.io/snapshots/",
  "Typesafe Releases" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "Sonatype OSS Releases"  at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.github.nscala-time" %% "nscala-time" % "1.8.0",
  "com.sclasen" %% "akka-kafka" % "0.0.10" % "compile",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.2",
  "org.codehaus.groovy" % "groovy" % "2.3.7",
  "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging-slf4j" % "2.1.2",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.2",
  "ch.qos.logback.contrib" % "logback-json-classic" % "0.1.2",
  "ch.qos.logback.contrib" % "logback-jackson" % "0.1.2",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-api" % "1.7.7",
  "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.2.2",
  "org.clapper" %% "argot" % "1.0.3",
  "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.2.1",
  "net.ceedubs" %% "ficus" % "1.0.1",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "anorm" % "2.3.6",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-native" % "3.2.10",
  "org.json4s" %% "json4s-jackson" % "3.2.10",
  "com.github.tototoshi" %% "scala-csv" % "1.1.2",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.2",
  "junit" % "junit" % "4.11",
  "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "0.8.1.1"
    exclude("javax.jms", "jms")
    exclude("com.sun.jdmk", "jmxtools")
    exclude("com.sun.jmx", "jmxri")
    exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-simple")
)

mainClass in assembly := Some("com.company.kafka.agent.MetamorphosisActor")
```

Any clues on how I can even figure out how to fix this merge problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

### Previous answer gives all the required feedback, but does not actually give any solution or steps to try out.

My error:

```
[error] (project/*:assembly) deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
[error] deduplicate: different file contents found in the following:
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/ch.qos.logback/logback-classic/jars/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
[error] /home/user/.ivy2/cache/org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
```

### Recommended way

track down conflicting dependency. For example, I do not want those classes:

```
org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class
org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMDCBinder.class
org.slf4j/slf4j-log4j12/jars/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar:org/slf4j/impl/StaticMarkerBinder.class
```

Call `sbt` (and make sure to use [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) plugin):

```
whatDependsOn org.slf4j slf4j-log4j12 1.7.10
```

Returns a list:

```
[info] org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.10
[info]   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.8.0
[info]   | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]   |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]   |   
[info]   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]   | +com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]   | 
[info]   +-org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.6
[info]     +-org.apache.curator:curator-client:2.7.1
[info]     | +-org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.7.1
[info]     | | +-org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.7.1
[info]     | | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     | | |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     | | |   
[info]     | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.8.0
[info]     | |   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     | |     +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     | |     
[info]     | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     |   
[info]     +-org.apache.curator:curator-framework:2.7.1
[info]     | +-org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.7.1
[info]     | | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     | |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     | |   
[info]     | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.8.0
[info]     |   +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     |     +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     |     
[info]     +-org.apache.curator:curator-recipes:2.7.1
[info]     | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     |   
[info]     +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:2.8.0
[info]     | +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]     |   +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
[info]     |   
[info]     +-org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:2.8.0
[info]       +-com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3 [S]
```

I need to track down `hadoop-common` dependency since it is the one that connects `com.github.atais:test_2.11:0.0.3` to the unwanted `org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.7.10`

And modify it:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.8.1" exclude("org.slf4j", "slf4j-log4j12")
```

### Easy way

simply add the merging strategy flag for conflicting paths:

```
assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  ...
  case PathList("org", "slf4j", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.first
  case x => (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly).value(x)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you're the hero we don't deserve

Answer (score 8):

The issue is that more than one dependency brings in `slf4j` transitive dependency which causes a conflict. The best way is to exclude that transitive dependency instead of using merging strategy of SBT assembly to resolve the conflict.

First you need to visualize where slf4j comes from (for all top level dependencies). You can use a tool like this [sbt-dependency-graph](https://github.com/jrudolph/sbt-dependency-graph) to get a visual diagram of all dependencies. Alternatively you can explore SBT settings from SBT command prompt or use a maven site like [this one](http://search.maven.org/) or [this one](http://mvnrepository.com/).

Once you locate duplicate dependencies use `exclude` the same way as you use in your build file. Leave only single `slf4j` transitive dependency. You can also exclude all `slf4j` transitive dependencies (see [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Library-Management.html#Exclude+Transitive+Dependencies) how) and manually add that `slf4j` dependency at top level.

Note that if your dependencies require multiple different versions of `slf4j` it might be problematic to pick a single version that works for all cases. Depends on binary compatibility.

Comment: Why however, is this not an issue for the same project in `sbt run`, but only in the packaging of the project?

Comment: @matanster when SBT packages it explicitly checks for conflicts, but when it simply runs it just uses the classpath. In JVM there is no exception for such cases - first class on the path wins.