# How do I handle MANIFEST.MF with sbt and Intellij?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, manifest.mf

I'm writing an application in Scala using IntelliJ and sbt (latest stable version on everything).
I can run and debug it just fine from within intellij but if I try to run the standalone artifact it complains that it can't find Main and I should add a MANIFEST.MF file in META-INF. If I add this manually to the jar, it runs fine. But if I add this to my source tree to be automatically included inn the jar, the program won't start in Intellij because 'duplicate MANIFEST.MF' and there isn't any one else. So I assume Intellij adds one on it's own.
I've tried all the tricks I've found regarding mergestrategy with no luck.

What is the correct this?

Comment: `sbt package` should provide a JAR with a proper manifest out of the box.

Comment: probably duplicate. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39856636/5122436