# assemblyMergeStrategy type error

Tags: scala, sbt

I am trying to set up a small project to have an aws-lambda written in scala:

```
javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.8", "-target", "1.8", "-Xlint")

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    name := "xxx",
    version := "0.1",
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
    retrieveManaged := true
  )

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-core"   % "1.1.0" % Provided,
  "com.amazonaws" % "aws-lambda-java-events" % "1.1.0" % Provided,
  "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "2.2.6" % Test
)

scalacOptions += "-deprecation"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly <<= (assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly) {
  (old) => {
    case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
    case x => MergeStrategy.first
  }
}
```

Results in :

> xxx/build.sbt:25: error: not found: value assemblyMergeStrategy
>   assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly <<= (assemblyMergeStrategy in
>   assembly) { ^ [error] Type error in expression

The source of inspiration was [this blog](https://chrislarson.me/blog/tutorial/lambda/2017/03/31/aws-lambda-scala.html).
[Also tried the provided version as `mergeStrategy` might have been replaced by `assemblyMergeStrategy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38394348/2085376).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you reference assembly plugin in your project/plugins.sbt file?
assemblyMergeStrategy is defined by the plugin.

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.3")
```

Comment: In newer versions, you put this in project/assembly.sbt . See https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly for latest info.